# fail to convert yelp dataset Json to csv with Python

Tags: python, json, csv, yelp

I am dealing with the yelp reviews dataset and trying to convert it from Json to csv based on the sample code from github: https://github.com/lovingawareness/Yelp-Challenge-Dataset/blob/master/convert.py but it fails and I cannnot figure it out. Could you please help me with it? Really appreciate.

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\jiang\OneDrive\Desktop\yelp_dataset")

import json
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

def convert(x):
    ''' Convert a json string to a flat python dictionary
    which can be passed into Pandas. '''
    ob = json.loads(x)
    for k, v in ob.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            ob[k] = ','.join(v)
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for kk, vv in v.items():
                ob['%s_%s' % (k, kk)] = vv
            del ob[k]
    return ob

for json_filename in glob('yelp_academic_dataset_review.json'):
    csv_filename = '%s.csv' % json_filename[:-5]
    print('Converting %s to %s' % (json_filename, csv_filename))
    df = pd.DataFrame([convert(line) for line in file(json_filename)])
    df.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

[image]

After changing 'file' into 'open', it still produces a large error as the figure shows below.
[image]

This problem has been addressed after taking advice from Michael Butscher, just need to revise one line in the last chunk. Really appreciate it.

```
for json_filename in glob('yelp_academic_dataset_review.json'):
    csv_filename = '%s.csv' % json_filename[:-5]
    print('Converting %s to %s' % (json_filename, csv_filename))
    df = pd.DataFrame([convert(line) for line in open(json_filename, encoding='utf-8')])
    df.to_csv(csv_filename, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

Comment: Use "open" instead of "file".

Comment: Hello Michael. I have tried open but it still does not work.

Comment: What means "does not work"? If it produces a large error message, edit the question to show it.

Comment: The error is shown in the second figure.

Comment: You must specify the right encoding (probably "UTF-8") in the call to "open".

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)